# error C3861: 'strcpy_y': identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

```
Pacient& operator = ( Pacient&p) {
  cout << "Operator = Pacient" << endl;
  delete [] this->nume;
  this->nume = new char[strlen(p.nume)+1];
  strcpy_y(this->nume,strlen(p.nume)+1,p.nume); // ERROR
  delete [] this->prenume;
  this->prenume = new char[strlen(p.prenume)+1];
  strcpy_y(this->prenume,strlen(p.prenume)+1,p.prenume); // ERROR
  this->varsta = p.varsta;
  return *this;
}
```

> 1>Compiling...
>   1>pacienti.cpp
>   1>f:\bob\facultate\semestrul iii\programareorientataobiect\proiect pacienti\proiect\proiect\pacienti.cpp(24) : error C3861: 'strcpy_y': identifier not found
>   1>f:\bob\facultate\semestrul iii\programareorientataobiect\proiect pacienti\proiect\proiect\pacienti.cpp(27) : error C3861: 'strcpy_y': identifier not found

I get this error. Why? What should I do to get rid of it?

Comment: What is `strcpy_y` anyway?

Comment: I assume `strncpy`. Either that or `strcpy_s`.

Comment: You could save yourself a lot of trouble by just using std::string here

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as `strcpy_y`, at least not in Standard C++.

Perhaps you meant `strcpy_s` [from WINAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx)?

If `strcpy_y` is a function you have created yourself, then you need to `#include` the file where it is declared.

Why use raw C-style strings in the first place?  Just use `std::string` allocated as a locat variable and all these problems go away.  Use `operator=` to copy the `string`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it's strcpy_s :D

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't know what `strcpy_y` is because you haven't declared it anywhere prior to that line in the current translation unit.

Either provide the declaration for `strcpy_y` (e.g. `#include` a relevant header, or forward declare it), or fix the typo if you meant to call some other function.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it can be help you:
`#include <string.h>`

But I don't recommended use strcpy_y in your code, because it's not C++.

Comment: Oh, my mistakes. I thought that we are talking about strcpy_s.